# Why can't I access sites that end in .dev?

Tags: flutter, dns, ip

I'm trying to access https://flutter.dev, but I'm not able to. I'll get a spinner for 30 seconds, followed by this error:

```
This site can’t be reached 
flutter.dev’s server IP address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

I thought it was my firewall at work, but I've tried it at home now too and it's still not working. I've tried it in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox, and also on my MacBook and iMac. Also tried it in regular and incognito browsing.

I'm able to access it on my iPhone with no problem. And no problem accessing any other sites on my laptop and desktop.

Any idea what could be going on and how to fix it?

Comment: it works fine on my laptop. looks like you are not the only one with this problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56143554/why-is-flutter-dev-not-reachable. what country are you based in? it might help the flutter team to fix the issue.

Comment: I had similar problem on my Mac. I fixed this by 1. Removing *.dev handling from dnsmasq configuration /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf 2. Removing /etc/resolver/dev. Give it a try