# Why is flutter.dev not reachable?

Tags: windows, flutter

I cant seem to access flutter.dev site, I tried from different browsers, devicesand networks but always get

## This site can’t be reached

#### flutter.dev took too long to respond.

Tried `tracert flutter.dev` and only got to homerouter and started to `timeout`

I have am currently on a fresh install of windows 10.

any help please?

Comment: it works fine on my laptop. looks like you are not the only one with this problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56142022/why-cant-i-access-sites-that-end-in-dev. what country are you based in? it might help the flutter team to fix the issue.

Comment: The website works well on my computer. check you network settings

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if flutter.dev is reachable from other devices as smartphone, pc, etc. If other devices could reach flutter.dev from the same network, check DNS settings, look at "C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts". Perhaps you are using something for local development e.g dnsmasq, in this case, all .dev domains could be pointed to your local machine. 
I hope, that my answer will be useful.

Comment: tried from an android device using mobile data, it worked. so I am now suspecting my wifi network, probably my rooter blocking it

Comment: On Mac I had dnsmasq installed and removed. After reinstalling I can reach flutter.dev again. So this is definitely local.